# PHP ZF: I can't debug my IndexController.php actions code

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug

I'm new to php and I'm using xampp, eclipse pdt, xdebug. I've set xdebug so that I can debug my site on apache but when I click 'debug as web page' in the eclipse ide only the breakpoint in the public/index.php and in the views get hit. If I put a breakpoin here

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // action body

    $this->view->s = "deam";
}
```

the debugger don't stop?! why is that? I can't debug the most important part of my application. :( Plese help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

iam not sure how eclipse is working, but i think you have to define the correct
entry point for the project.

In Netbeans i can set the index.php as "startpage" than iam able to debug my application.

Comment: yes this is my first page from when the debugger starts but when I hit F8 to resume the debugger don't stop at my controller where I also have a breakpoint.